# Need To Make Sure NSFetchResultsController Is Called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a NSFetchResultsController but I need to make sure it is called before a line in my `viewDidLoad` is called.

The line is `self.todaySession = (Session *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:0];`

Is there a way I can make sure the fetch is called before this line is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about by inserting a line that calls your fetch results controller just above that line?

You will get a crash from that line of code. The integer literal `0` is not an `NSIndexPath` instance. You probably want something like this:

```
self.todaySession = (id)[frc objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWitRow:0 
                                                                    section:0]];
```